# ASP.NET MVC Upgrade guide

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a small ASP.NET MVC application developed using the latest beta version.

What would be an easy to follow step-by-step guide to upgrade to the RC [released yesterday](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/01/27/asp-net-mvc-1-0-release-candidate-now-available.aspx)?

What key changes would I have to apply to get it working in the new version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [release notes](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=137661&clcid=0x409), the steps to follow are listed there.

Repeated here for your convenience.

There are not many changes between the Beta and the RC releases. However, you will need to make a few changes to your applications after installing the Beta release. Most of these changes are apparent when you try to compile your application by using the latest release, so we do not list every possible change. 
The following list describes some of the changes that you must make.

- Update the references to the
  following assemblies to point to the
  RC versions:
- System.Web.Abstractions.dll
- System.Web.Routing.dll
- System.Web.Mvc.d

ll
Note   If you are running ASP.NET 3.5 SP1, you need to update only the System.Web.Mvc assembly reference.

By default, these assemblies are located in the following folder:

%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC RC

- After you have made these changes, compile your application and resolve any compilation errors. Most of the errors will be the result of one of the breaking changes listed earlier.
- Update the  section the Web.config file In the Views folder to match the following example. (The changed elements are in bold.)

Answer (score 4):

I think the [release notes](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=137661&clcid=0x409) has a fairly good guide.

Answer (score 0):

There's some issues not mentioned in release note. Read this for more info:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1377139.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You also make sure to add the following tag to your web.config file:

```
<system.web.extensions/>
```

It took me a lot of effort to figure it out since it's been nowhere documented.